# Write a generic method to parse specific field from a JSON string

Tags: java, json, parsing, key, key-value

I am trying to write a method that would fetch the "device_identifier" value from a json string that I have. The json string looks like this

```
{"widget": {
"debug": "on",
"window": {
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
},
"image": { 
    "src": "Images/Sun.png",
    "name": "sun1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 250,
    "alignment": "center"
},
"text": {
    "data": "Click Here",
    "size": 36,
    "style": "bold",
    "name": "text1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 100,
    "alignment": "center",
    "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
}
```

}}

What I managed to write is this:

```
        private static String getCustomFieldInauth(Object customFields, String fieldName) throws IOException {
    if (customFields == null) {
        return null;
    }

    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser parser  = factory.createParser(fieldName);

    while(!parser.isClosed()){
        JsonToken jsonToken = parser.nextToken();

        if(JsonToken.FIELD_NAME.equals(jsonToken)){
            String currentKey = parser.getCurrentName();

            jsonToken = parser.nextToken();

            if(fieldName.equals(currentKey)){
                return parser.getValueAsString();
            }
        }
    }
    return parser.getValueAsString();
}
```

Right now, I am just trying to map the JSON as a key value pair. What should my approach be ? How is this achievable. Can someone help me.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Did you try using a Java Json parser like Json Jackson or Gson? Your method expects a Map and not a Json String.

Comment: @PauloPedroso No, I haven't. But I was thinking of it. However, I was wondering if Java has JSON parse, I know it is in JS. But, I don't know.

Comment: Give them a try. It will make your life easier.